# Angular ng-style issue

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to change the myStyle in the following snippet as {color:'red'; border:1px solid red} but no luck. Any idea why?

```
<input type="button" value="set" ng-click="myStyle={color:'red'}">
<input type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myStyle={}">
<br/>
<span ng-style="myStyle">Sample Text</span>
<input type="text" ng-style="myStyle" value="Sample Text" />
<pre>myStyle={{myStyle}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myStyle` object is a little off. Replace your `;` with `,` and put `' '` around the value of the property.

Instead of

```
{color:'red'; border:1px solid red}
```

Use this (within your ng-click)

```
{color:'red', border:'1px solid red'}
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kv1m3SDwr6ENkf9vJvWV?p=preview)

Comment: I got messed up with CSS tricks. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: No worries. Glad it was a minor change for you.

Answer (score 0):

In **myStyle** you should put valid js object like

```
myStyle={ color:'red', borderWidth: '1px', borderColor: 'red', borderStyle: 'solid' }
```

see working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tabalinas/L6yn3/

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-style syntax is a little off. Css should be delimited by commas, and the css values should all be wrapped in single quotes.

Like so `{color:'red', border:'1px solid red'}`